# Please verify this matrix algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$(AB)C$
$=(AB)(CI)$
$=(AB)(C(AA^{-1}))$
$=(AB)((CA)A^{-1}))$
$=((AB)(CA))A^{-1}$

I tried computing this in numpy(python) but got did not get correct result.

```
from numpy import *
import random as rand
A = [[rand.randrange(10) for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
B = [[rand.randrange(10) for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]
C = [[rand.randrange(10) for i in range(10)] for i in range(10)]

ABC = matmul(matmul(A,B),C)
if(linalg.det(A) != 0):
    ABC2 = matmul(matmul(matmul(A,B),matmul(C,A)),linalg.inv(A))
    print(ABC == ABC2)
```

This results in false.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Did you verify that the random matrix A choosed is effectively invertible?

Comment: @FedericoFallucca I just verified. It is invertible. Its determinant is not 0.

Comment: Did you verify that matmul(A, B) is equal to AB and not BA? It depends by how this function is defined.

Comment: @FedericoFallucca Yes I verified that too. It is equal to AB. Also I edited the code to include a check for determinant. 
And is the derivation above correct?

Comment: Maybe the problem is the computation of the matrix $A$. It could happen that the inverse is described by fractions and it approximates them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matrix algebra is correct. The two expressions are theoretically equal; however, they may not be equal when numerically calculated.

`==` is not a reliable way to compare the results of two numerical calculations, unless they're both exact. Your `ABC` may be exact enough (within machine precision), but I doubt `ABC2` due to the calculation of $A^{-1}$. Inverse calculations generally have numerical 'errors', which are worse when the condition number of the starting matrix is worse.

So it could be that by human inspection, `ABC2` looks reasonably close enough to `ABC`. However, `==` does not accept 'reasonably close'; the two values usually have to be close on the order of machine precision.

I don't know what people generally use to test two matrices for numerical closeness. My naive suggestion is to calculate the maximum absolute difference between the corresponding elements of `ABC` and `ABC2`, and if it is small enough for you, 'declare' that the two calculations are numerically close enough.

Comment: Thankyou. That was the problem.